# Manage conflict between componentwillrecieveprops and onChange function

Tags: reactjs

I am working with a pretty complex react app that someone else has written. I want to set a default value for a form field at the end of a message thread.

The child render function maybe called several times before all of the data is loaded. And the default value for my form component is dependent on the last value in the thread.

For that reason I am setting the replyType in the constructor and have some logic in getReplyType that calculates based on the current Props:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      replyType: this.getReplyType(),
    };
  }
```

That won't render the right value if it took 3 times before we got all the data from the parent. So I use a call like this to update the value in my form:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      replyType: this.getReplyType(nextProps),
    });
  }
```

This gets me the initial state I want. The problem is that componentWillReceiveProps is called everytime, including after a manual selection by the user. It doesn't override the selection text, but breaks some logic on how the CSS is rendered...

```
changeReplyType = ({ value }) => {
  this.setState({
    replyType: value,
  });
}
```

QUESTION: Is there a way to prevent `componentWillReceiveProps` from running if the change was triggered by the event handler?

Answer (score 0):

i had to use an if statement inside the componentWillReceiveProps and a new prop

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // setState when props change from pending to not pending
    // prevents function from being called when changeReplyType updates state
    if (!nextProps.isPending && this.props.isPending) {
      this.setState({
        replyType: this.getReplyType(nextProps),
      });
    }
  }
```